# C++ run time with different loops

Tags: c++, c++11

Why do both of these loops take the same amount of time, shouldn't the if statement make the first single loop much slower?

```
// Example program                                                                                     
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int counter = 0;
  #ifdef single
  cout << "one for loop\n";
  for(int i =0;i<10000000;i++)
    {
      if(i != 50000) counter+=i;
    }
#else
  cout << "two loops\n";
  for(int i = 0;i<50000;i++)
    {
      counter+=i;
    }
  for(int i = 50001;i<10000000;i++)
    {
      counter+=i;
    }
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

I get, for time, the following results:
time ./test 
one for loop

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.002s

AND

two loops

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.002s

I did some research and it said it is cause of branching but I'm not sure if that is the only reason, it was compiled as

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 test.cpp -Dsingle -o test
```

Comment: If you add the `-S` switch to generate assembly, you'll see that both programs are producing identical code (except for the actual strings).  I suspect the entire loop has been optimized away, since it is completely deterministic at compile-time.

Comment: Compare the resulting machine code maybe? Does the code actually contain any loops, of does the compiler notice the undefined behaviour and simply eliminates everything?

Comment: So if i were to make the exit condition for the loop i<x where x is inputted by the user (cin) then it should be different? time to find out...

Answer (score 2):

The overall loop barely puts a dent, in modern, multi-gigahertz CPUs, enormous level 1 & 2 CPU caches, and blazingly fast memory.

You're going to have to come up with two alternative execution paths that have way, way, more substantive differences, than a single, puny if() statement like that, before you can see any kind of a difference.

Think of it this way: modern CPUs have all sorts of crazy pipelining, that make it possible for the CPU to execute not just the current instruction, but several instructions after that. All at the same time. When the current instruction is the loop increment, the CPU has already likely figured out what the next if() will evaluate to, and what to do after that. All during the same set of clock cycles.

Comment: yeah I was thinking of pipelining too but just wasn't sure. Thank you!

Comment: This sounds good but it's not quite true. On my (admittedly not a supercomputer, but still an i5) laptop using gcc-5.3, the first one takes about 5ms while the second one takes about 2.5ms, averaged over 10 trials of each. So the time is measurable. However, to get the results I had to convince gcc to actually compile the loop; see my answer. (clang does a better optimization, in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a more accurate benchmark if you actually do something with `counter` (like output it). Otherwise, gcc will figure out that the computation of `counter` is unnecessary, and so it won't bother wasting time doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fact that you're not consuming the variable `counter` is making the compiler to optimize it out. Try putting a `cout << counter << endl;` before `return 0;`.